# Routing multiple static IPs to a single websever, hosting multiple sites

Tags: networking, router

I inherited this network configuration from previous employees. Essentially we have fourteen static IPs assigned by our service provider, the current modem/router correctly passes the information into the server.

I need to replace the outdated and dying router, but it's password protected and I can't access it's settings.

First I looked at NAT, but they're all public so as I understand it, I shouldn't need that. Then I looked at the firewall, and the only one in place is within the server itself, it's logs don't seem to indicate that it's doing anything different with the new router in place…

I don't know where to look next…

Comment: so, your real problem is to not get access to the old router? get the password. someone in your company will have it. if not: ask the previous employee. if you can't get any access to that machine: setup a new one, place it between your isp and your current router and forward ANYTHING to the old router. then start setting up new routes one by one.

Comment: That is a very good idea, I'll give it a shot and see what happens.